# Laplace's equation for boundary conditions.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics

I need to solve $\nabla^2 V(x,y)$ for 
$$\begin{cases} \text{$V \to 0$ when $x \to \infty$} \\\text{$V = 0$ when $y = 0$}\\\text{$V = 0$ when $y = a$}\\\text{$V = V_0$ when $0 \lt y \lt \dfrac a2, x = 0  $}\\\text{$V = -V_0$ when $\dfrac a 2 \lt y \lt a, x = 0 $}\end{cases}$$

$$\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

Using separation of variables, $V = X(x)Y(y)$

I got,

$$X^{\prime\prime}_x = k^2 X(x), Y^{\prime\prime}_y = -k^2 Y(x)$$

I solved these, 
$$V(x,y) = (Ae^{kx} + B e^{kx} )(C\sin ky + D \cos ky)$$

Using first three constraints, I got

$$V(x,y) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1}C_ne^{-n\pi x/a}\sin \left(\frac{n\pi y}{a}\right) \text{ for } n \in \Bbb Z_+$$

$$V(0, y) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1}C_n\sin \left(\frac{n\pi y}{a}\right) = \begin{cases}-V_0 \qquad \dfrac a 2 \lt y \lt a \\ V_0 \qquad 0 \lt y \lt \dfrac a 2\end{cases}$$

At this point I am confused as how to find $C_n$. I thought I will multiply by $\sin (\frac{m\pi y}{a})$ and integrate from $0$ to $\frac{a}{2}$ for bottom cases and likewise $\frac{a}{2}$ to $a$ for top case but I think that will give me two values for same $C_m$, which can't true. What should I do ?

---

Edit :
$$ \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1}C_n \int_0^{a} \sin\left(\dfrac{m\pi y}{a}\right) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{a}\right)dy = \int_0^{a} V(y) \sin\left(\dfrac{m\pi y}{a}\right)dy = V_0\left(\int_0^{a/2}\sin\left(\dfrac{m\pi y}{a}\right)dy  - \int_{a/2}^{a}\sin\left(\dfrac{m\pi y}{a}\right)dy\right) = \dfrac{V_0a}{\pi m}\left(-\cos(\pi m /2) + 1 +cos (m\pi) -\cos\left( \dfrac{m\pi}{2}\right)\right) = \dfrac{V_0 a}{\pi m}\left(1-2\cos\left(\dfrac{m\pi}{2}\right)+\cos(m\pi)\right)$$

$$\therefore C_m =  \dfrac{8V_0}{\pi m}$$ for odd $n$ where $m = 2n$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: I'd suggest you solve the problem in each subdomain with an auxiliary condition $V(x,a/2)=g(x)$ for $g$ unknown. It will ultimately turn out by symmetry considerations that $g(x)=0$, but that should fall out of the solution. Alternatively you can solve a regularized problem, for example $V(0,y)=-V_0 \tanh((y-a/2)/\epsilon)$ for $0<\epsilon \ll 1$ and then send $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: @Ian I don't know if I understood you properly or not, but I think you mean to say that I find two solution for $V$, one valid in lower domain and other in  upper domain.

Comment: Yes. And then you force them to agree, which determines what $g(x)$ is.

Comment: @Ian Please look at the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find $C_n$ multiplying by $\sin(\frac{m\pi y}{a})$ and integrating from $0$ to $a$: define
$$
V_0(y)=
\begin{cases}
V_0, &  0<y<\frac{a}{2} \\
-V_0, & \frac{a}{2}<y<a
\end{cases}
$$

knowing that
$$
\int_0^a \sin(\frac{n\pi y}{a}) \sin(\frac{m\pi y}{a}) dy=
\begin{cases}
0, &  \text{if $n\neq m$} \\
\frac{a}{2}, & \text{if $n= m$}
\end{cases}
$$
you arrive at
$$
C_n=\frac{2}{a}\int_0^a V_0(y) \sin(\frac{n\pi y}{a}) dy
$$
now you just split the integral from $0$ to $\frac{a}{2}$ and from $\frac{a}{2}$ to $a$ and integrate; $C_n$ will be zero for some $n$ and non-zero for others (e.g. $C_2$).

Comment: Yes I did this, please see the edit.

Comment: @123 You can't use the orthogonality if you integrate only from $0$ to $\frac{a}{2}$. For example the integral of $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3}x)\sin(\frac{3\pi}{3}x)$ from $0$ to $\frac{3}{2}$ isn't $0$

Comment: But you said to split the integral from $0$ to $a/2$ and $a/2$ to $a$ in the last line.

Comment: Yes, but I used orthogonality before splitting

Comment: The method I used is general, for any $V_0(y)$, and at the end I split the integral only because your $V_0(y)$ isn't continuous

Comment: hmmm, yes you are correct. This is a easy problem to sort, I just need to divide by $2$.

Comment: I sorted the problem in the edit, still I don't get a single expression for $C_m$.

Comment: Now you can't integrate from $0$ to $a$ because the relation you are using holds only for $y<\frac{a}{2}$, so you can't integrate outside this interval. I would be really surprised if you managed to find a way to solve this problem dividing (from the start) the domain in $0<y<\frac{a}{2}$ and $\frac{a}{2}<y<a$ (without using Ian's $g(x)$); in this problems I've always found one expression for $C_m$, never two that had to be equal

Comment: Sorry I now realise my mistake and sorry for my stupidity, can you check my edit again ? I think I got it this time. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No problem! I had to practice a lot too at the beginning. There is only a sign error, the third line should be $$\frac{V_0 a}{\pi m}(1-2\cos(\frac{m\pi}{2})+\cos(m\pi))$$

Comment: BTW, the answer $\frac{4V_0}{\pi m}$ (you forgot a two) is the correct answer if $V_0(y) = V_0$ for all $0<y<a$

Comment: Should not the answer be $\dfrac{8V_0}{\pi m}$ because for $m = 2n$, $1 + 1 - 2 cos(n\pi) = 4$ where $n$ is odd.

Comment: Exactly, the answer is $C_m=\frac{8V_0}{\pi m}$ if m is even but not divisible by $4$, and $C_m=0$ otherwise

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciate your patience and help.